# Assumptions in logistic regression for applying LRT and AIC criteria

Tags: logistic, aic, assumptions, likelihood-ratio

I have a question. Do the following assumptions in logistic regression

1. Linearity between the log-odds and the continuous covariates
2. Non multicollinearity
3. Absence of outliers

need to be satisfied in order to apply AIC or LRT criteria for variable selection?

As far as I know, those assumptions must be satisfied if you want to ensure the p-values associated with the model coefficients are reliable. But I am not sure about the other criteria.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to use a test for variable selection; see e.g. Hyndman ["Statistical tests for variable selection"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tests2/) in the context of forecasting. (AIC is a better choice.)

Comment: I don't think variable selection has anything to do with the assumptions of a model, per se, but it is a good idea to bear that in mind when selecting variables together, especially with the multicollinearity assumption